# How to disable power to the mouse and keyboard after shutdown? 

Tags: usb, motherboard

After my computer shuts down, I still have the power to the keyboard and mouse. This causes both the keyboard and mouse to have lights that remain lit while the system is off. How do I change this, so when I shutdown these also turn off?

Comment: If your computer has an on-off switch on the power supply at the back, where the cable goes in, and you turn that off, does that disable the lights on the keyboard and mouse?

Comment: @RandolphWest - Yes that does but having to do that every time can be a real pain.

Comment: I asked the question to confirm my suspicions. Certain motherboards don't actually disable power to the USB ports after shutdown. This is by design, so you may be out of luck.

Comment: Hmm, I will be looking at the paperwork to see if I can disable this in the settings. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I posted an answer. However, do you know what your make and model of motherboard you have?

Comment: @SgtOJ - ASRock N68-VS3 FX

Comment: @Lynda I believe your question has been solved. Let me know if you still are having problems after completing the steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is normal with some motherboards. It's due to the +5v AUX being active. Some motherboard have a jumper that can disable it.  You can also check your BIOS to see if you are able to disable a setting that allows your system to be awake via keyboard or mouse signal.

Your best bet is to read the motherboard's Owners Manual to find a solution on exactly how to disable it for your motherboard.

---

## Instructions to Disable +5V-Standby for ASRock N68-VS3 FX

[image]

*Source: This was taken directly out of the [manual](http://download.asrock.com/manual/N68-VS3%20FX.pdf) for the ASRock N68-VS3 FX motherboard*

Comment: Thanks for your help, I read that in the manual last night. I am just not comfortable messing with jumpers etc in the computer. I can change a video card or RAM but I generally leave the rest alone. But I will look into it. After looking through the BIOS I did not see any option that might allow me to disable it. What is interesting is if I have the power switch off then turn the power switch on the keyboard/mouse do not show any power going to them. Only after shutdown. Thanks again for your help.